# Using type hinting in Python 3.4 vs Python 3.5 gives syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

I'm using Pycharm and Python 3.4 on different servers to execute scripts I've made. I'm using type hinting in my code. Now someone from my work have executed my code on a Python 3.5 installation and is getting a syntax error on my type hinting. I do not "knowingly" use any modules for type hinting in Python 3.4 IE I am not using the typing module.

```
def run(iargs) -> int:
               ^ syntax error
```

Could it be that Python 3.4 not even reading these tags where 3.5 does. ?

**EDIT**

I've done the following test

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 28 2016, 10:12:53)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def Add(r,l) -> int:
...   return int(r + l)
...
>>> Add(3,5)
8
>>>

Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def Add(r,l) -> int:
...   return int(r + l)
...
>>> Add(3,5)
8
```

So there are no problems regarding version of the python 3.4 or 3.5 however when I execute my script I get the following

```
  File "test.py", line 235
    def run(iargs) -> int:
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Regards

Comment: Yes, Python 3.4 does not understand a syntax of type hints.

Comment: So the is why it only "works" in 3.4? I am using it in pycharm. But what is wrong with the syntax and why does it not work in 3.5 because i guess it should?

Comment: You are not running it in 3.4 when it works. Triple check used interpreters.

Comment: I am. Im running 3.4.3 i known because ive only installed this version. The problem was one of our developers using my scripts on his own test server.

Comment: The syntax is supported in Python 3.4, but they are merely _function annotations_  ([`PEP 3107`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)) not _type hints_ ([`PEP 484`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)).

Comment: @NunoAndré More or less, I think. At least I just ran a Python script on which I was using Python 3.9 and it's running normally on Python 3.4 with PyCharm 2020.3. I only had to install the `typing` module and now it runs normally. No syntax errors at all.

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.4 does not support inline type annotations. The syntax you used was introduced in 3.5 and up

If you want type annotations to work in 3.4 you need to make them a comment like so:

```py
def run(iargs) # type: (str) -> str
```

On top of that you will need to install `typing` module from `pypi`. Also worth noting is that the type hint inside of a comment is not forwards compatible to >=3.5

Comment: I don't see any difference with this line of code compared to the same line of code that the OP says causes a syntax error.

Comment: Oh my bad, the comments dissapeared on copy paste.

Comment: This isn't true! Function annotations were added in 3.0: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/

Comment: Aside from what falcojr said (which seems to be right - I just tested and no errors on Python 3.4), why do you say it's not compatible with Python >= 3.5? It's only a comment anyways. If it's not understood, it's a normal comment. And I think the type hints (comment or not) don't really do anything on the Python interpreter. I think they're only useful for an IDE (like PyCharm) and/or for someone trying to understand the program. Please correct me if I'm wrong though. I've still to take a complete course on Python.